# Not able to play videos properly in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, vlc

After the update any video I play through vlc just lags and pixel-ates , also I am unable to play any youtube video in both firefox and chrome. My graphic card is GeForce GTX 860M/PCIe/SSE2. I have tried reinstalling nvidia graphic drives but that still doesn't do the trick...Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem after upgrading.  I have a 960.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu restricted extras ? If not then it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to disable "Hardware-accelerate decoding" in preferences->input/codecs

Source:
https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/16877

Answer (score 0):

For what it worth, with Ignacio's answer, the video playback enhanced a bit for me but not completely, after changing my graphic card's driver + Ignacio's answer it works like a charm :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable hardware accelerated codecs and that will work. Preferences->input/codecs